# Regex that will extract the string between two known strings

Tags: regex, string, extract

I'd like to extract the email addresses from the following input text:

```
    Junk
    more junk
    Members:
     member: user1@somedomain.com (user)
     member: user2@somedomain.com (user)
     member: user3@somedomain.com (user)
     member: user4@somedomain.com (user)
     member: user5@somedomain.com (user)
     member: user6@somedomain.com (user)
    even more junk
```

The addresses are consistently found between " member: " and " (user)".  The following expression output an array of email addresses in an online regex tester:

```
    /  member: (.*) /gi
```

I took the expression and made a function that matches the appropriate lines but includes "member: " in the output.

```
    function test() {
      var str = 'Junk\nmore junk\nMembers:\n member: user1@somedomain.com (user)\n member: user2@somedomain.com (user)\n member: user3@somedomain.com (user)\n member: user4@somedomain.com (user)\n member: user5@somedomain.com (user)\n member: user6@somedomain.com (user)\neven more junk';
      var test = str.match(/ member: (.*) /gi);
    }

    Output: 
    [ member: user1@somedomain.com ,  member: user2@somedomain.com ,  member: user3@somedomain.com ,  member: user4@somedomain.com ,  member: user5@somedomain.com ,  member: user6@somedomain.com ]
```

I am fairly new to Regex but have experimented with positive and negative lookahead, but can't seem to find a combo that works.

```
    Solution: 

    function regexExample() {
      var myString = 'Junk\nmore junk\nMembers:\n member: user1@somedomain.com (user)\n member: user2@somedomain.com (user)\n member: user3@somedomain.com (user)\n member: user4@somedomain.com (user)\n member: user5@somedomain.com (user)\n member: user6@somedomain.com (user)\neven more junk';
      var myRegexp = / member: (.*) /gi;
      var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
      while (match != null) {
        Logger.log (match[1]);
        match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
      }
   }
```

Comment: The easiest way is to just use `RegExp#exec` in a loop.

Comment: @Wiktor, thanks for looking at my question.  I don't think the question you linked to is the same.  I can already access the groups in the output.  The issue is that they include "member: " and I only want the email portion.  I already have a method to iterate and strip the undesired portion, but I am looking for a more elegant regex way, which I think can be done with one expression.  The correct (email only) results are generated with an online regex tester using the expression I posted above.  Any ideas on how I can tune the expression to work in javascript match would be appreciated.

Comment: @Wiktor, my apologies, I didn't understand the nuance of accessing the second array, now I do.  I edited the post with the solution to my specific example based on the linked question.  Thx again!